# How to render contents of a component that renders another component via slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

as shown in the code posted below, the component `ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue` contains a `button` with a named `slot`. the component `NDVIComparisonGui.vue` renders `ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue`.
i want the `App.vue` to render `NDVIComparisonGui.vue` and consequently, `ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue` as well.

below is my attempt. when i run the code, i see only the contents of `<img>` but the button is never rendered.

please let me know why the button is not rendered and how to solve it.

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <NDVIComparisonGui></NDVIComparisonGui>
</template>

<script>
import NDVIComparisonGui from './components/NDVIComparisonGui.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    NDVIComparisonGui
  }
}
</script>
```

**NDVIComparisonGui.vue**:

```
<template>
    <ButtonDigitizePolygon @click="onDigitizePolygon()" :isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled="isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled">
        <template v-slot:slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel>
            {{ compPropsIsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon }}
        </template>
</ButtonDigitizePolygon>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { ButtonDigitizePolygon } from './ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue';

let isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled = ref(false);

export default {
    name: 'NDVIComparisonGui',
    date() {
        return {
            isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled,
        };
    },
    components: {
        ButtonDigitizePolygon,
    },
    props: {
    },
};
</script>
```

**ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue**:

```
<template>
<button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="clsDigitizePolygonBtn" :disabled="isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled">
    <slot name="slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel"></slot>
</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    date() {
        return {
            btnDigitizePolyhonState: this.isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled,
        };
    },
    props: {
        isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: where did you define `compPropsIsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i want to implement it later in NDVICoparisonGui.vue. so far it is not implenented...would it be the issue that causes the problem please?

Comment: in `NDVIComparisonGui` try to define `isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled:false` directly in data option without using `ref`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim `isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled` is defined in `NDVIComparisonGui.vue`

Comment: I mean `data(){ return { isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled:false }}`, and remove the ref above the export default and its importation

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i added to NDVIComparisonGui.vue the following: in ' data() {isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled:false}} ` but i get an error saying `isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled` is assigned to value but never used

Comment: You should do `:isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled="isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled"` you forget the double quotes `""`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes, i forgot to adapt the question, but in my vs code the qoutes were added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your NDVIComparisonGui.vue:

1. `import { ButtonDigitizePolygon }` should be `import ButtonDigitizePolygon`
2. it is `data(){  }` instead of `date(){}`

If you just copy your components to Vue SFC Playground, all the errors will be right there: https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: Thanks for your effort..I will acknowledge once tested.